# THC-Hydra - one good pass = shows all valid

Tags: passwords, brute-force

As in title.
I'm testing my router security and I came up with problem.

```
hydra 192.168.0.1 http-get-form "/:un=^USER^&pw=^PASS^:User Name or Password is incorrect." -L usernames -P passwords
```

usernames : `admin`

passwords : `admin`, `root`, `toor`, `1234`, `realpassword`(correct one)

I get: `1 of 1 target successfully completed, 5 valid passwords found`

Only `realpassword` is the correct one but Hydra says **all of them are good**.

When I go to `192.168.0.1`, which is router page, cookie (I guess) from Hydra allows me to be logged in. Still, executing this command does not provide me password, only session.

Q: How can I find out what password is real?

```
[SOLVED]
```

**I had to pick 'false response' which was visible for me but not from 'bad login' page source.**

Comment: you didn't tell hydra what a failed password looked like

Comment: `"User Name or Password is incorrect."` isn't enough?

Comment: Hydra will behave as you specify if it can't properly find that string. Double-check the string, syntax, case, etc.